# Why don't these mismatched shader variables produce a linker error?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am trying to throw an exception and abort my program when something fails during shader compile and link. I have introduced a typo: naming the output variable from my vertex shader something different from the expected input variable in my fragment shader. I would expect this to fail on link, but everything works fine (and the value of the variable in the fragment shader just ends up being 0). In particular, `glGetProgramiv(id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);` is setting success to true. What is going on?

**Vertex shader**:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
out vec4 vertexColo; // NOTE THE MISSPELLING HERE

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
    vertexColo = vec4(1.0 - aPos.y, 0.8 - aPos.y, aPos.x, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment shader**:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec4 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vertexColor;
}
```

**Test code:**

```cpp
namespace btv {

namespace {
static void test_compile(unsigned id, const char* path)
{
    int success;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        constexpr size_t BUF_SIZE = 1024;
        char buf[BUF_SIZE];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, BUF_SIZE, NULL, buf);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Shader at path: " << path << " failed with message: "
            << buf;
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
}

static void test_link(unsigned id, const char* v_path, const char* f_path)
{
    int success;
    glGetProgramiv(id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        constexpr size_t BUF_SIZE = 1024;
        char buf[BUF_SIZE];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(id, BUF_SIZE, NULL, buf);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Program with v shader: " << v_path << ", f shader: " << f_path
           <<  " failed with message: " << buf;
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }
}
}

Program::Program(const char* v_path, const char* f_path)
{
    std::string v_src = slurp(v_path);
    std::string f_src = slurp(f_path);

    const char *v_c = v_src.data();
    const char *f_c = f_src.data();


    unsigned v_shdr = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(v_shdr, 1, &v_c, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(v_shdr);
    test_compile(v_shdr, v_path);


    unsigned f_shdr = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(f_shdr, 1, &f_c, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(f_shdr);
    test_compile(f_shdr, f_path);

    id = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(id, v_shdr);
    glAttachShader(id, f_shdr);
    glLinkProgram(id);
    test_link(id, v_path, f_path);
}
} // namespace btv
```

Comment: In general this should cause a link time error, since the input variable `vertexColor` is static used in the fragment shader, but no corresponding output variable is declared in the vertex shader. It should give something like : *"error: "vertexColor" not declared as an output from the previous stage"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is related to GLSL version. In the [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#storage-qualifiers) (4.3.4 Input Variables) it is clearly specified, that it is a link-time error, if an input  variable is static used, but no corresponding output variable is declared in the previous stage.

This part of the specification is missing in the [OpenGL Shading Language 3.30 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf).

Change the GLSL version to (e.g.) 4.60 (`#version 460 core`) and you'll get the expected error.
e.g.

> "error: "vertexColor" not declared as an output from the previous stage"